# Short Science fiction story about a group of people trying to get to a portal that people believe leads to paradise

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

I'm looking for the name of a short science fiction story, that I read in the early 1980s. It had a heavy cold war vibe to it, so it's probably much older.

The story is about a group of people trying to get to a portal/rift that appeared on Earth one day without explanation. There is some kind of myth/legend that going through the portal will either take you to some kind of paradise or allow you to ascend to a higher state of being that's the equivalent of paradise.

The group are co-ed, and various ages, and they are each going to the portal/rift for different reasons. The meet up on the road near the beginning of the story and get separated near to the end.

The story has a post apocalyptic feel to it, as if the number of people who have gone through the rift, or who have tried to claim it, has destroyed society. I don't remember the exact details.

There was one particular scene that I remember where group take shelter in a farm house, and the farmer tries to get the girl in the group to stay. His wife can't have children, and he offers to take care of her if she has his child. She agrees but it nervous, so he gives her some kind of drug, probably LSD, she freaks out and runs away.

At the end of the story she realises that she's pregnant and she doesn't want to go into the rift, but she is caught up in a crowd and pushed through it.

I think that the rift was called "The River", and that the title of the story may have played on that theme.

Comment: This is obviously the same as [Title/Author of a short story about a group of people trying to get to a rift called the "river" that is supposed to lead to paradise?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253955/title-author-of-a-short-story-about-a-group-of-people-trying-to-get-to-a-rift-ca) Sadly 18 months on that previous question has no answer.